# Asp.Net MVC - how would i maintain user state in azure in my application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I know that there are a few questions like this, but the question is more in respect to this specifict situation.

Im developing a platform for taking tests online. A test is a set of images and belonging questions. Its being hosted on Azure and using MVC 4.

How I would love that if the user have taken half the test and the brower crashes or something makes it deviate from the test and comes back, it will give the option to resume.

I have one idea my self, but would like to know if theres other options. I was considering to use the localstorage. When a user starts a test, the information for the test is saved in localstorage and every time he moved on to a new image, it updates the local state. Then if the test-player is loaded it will check if any ongoing tests are avalible.

How could i do it? any one witch similar problem/solution.

Answer (score 1):

Local Storage is not a good choice, because it is specific to each instance.  That means if you have two instances of a Web Role (the recommended minimum), then each instance would have it's own local storage.  They are not shared, and there is no way to access local storage on a specific machine.

You really have two options.  You could use a database like SQL Azure, or use [Azure caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx). Azure caching is probably easier, since it's super easy to serialize/deserialize complex objects, but the downside is that caching is only valid for 72 hours.  If a cached object isn't accessed/updated in 72 hours, it gets purged.

Comment: I was talking about local Storage in html 5 browser, sorry for the misleading name.

Comment: Caching sound interesting, might look into that also. 72hours is more than needed. Its just incase of browser crashes and such.

Comment: Yes, I thought you were talking about Azure's local storage.  In Azure, you can create some temp storage on each instance, but it is not durable, and not shareable.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you storing this information on the client browser. The user has access to local storage, cookies, etc ... and could modify it. You could store the test start time in your database on the server. Then every time the user sends a request to the server in order to answer a question you would verify if the test is still active or the maximum allowed time has elapsed.

Comment: Its not a problem that a user has access to the data on the client. Its only whats visible to him in the test anyway. The validation of his answer will first happen when he commits to the server